# Many to Many Lookup Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, many-to-many, lookup

I have a database that contains a table "tbl_Formulation" that pulls multiple values of StockID from the same table "tbl_MaterialStock" via five different queries. I am designing a form that looks up the material relating to each of these StockID values in an earlier table "tbl_material".

How do I lookup the Material for a specific stock usage in my formulation form. I've tried using dlookup to do this but I can't work out a way to specify the lookup of a specific type of StockID.

I've attached a couple of pictures to try to explain the problem better.

Relationship Structure
[image: Relationship Structure]

One StockID type
[image: One StockID type]

Another
[image: Another]

Current control source code
[image: Current control source code]

A lil simplified explanation in paint.
[image: A simplified explanation in paint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run an `INNER JOIN` across *tbl_Material*, *tbl_MaterialStock*, and corresponding query in the combo boxes's `RowSource` query. Below demonstrates for *Filler*:

```sql
SELECT m.Material, q.StockID 
FROM (tbl_Material m
INNER JOIN tbl_MaterialStock s
ON m.MaterialID = s.MaterialID)
INNER JOIN qry_Filler q
ON q.StockID = s.StockID
```

Be sure to specify

```
Format tab
Column Count: 2

Data tab
Bound Column: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I used nested DLookups to solve this, like so

```
=DLookUp("[Material]","[tbl_Material]","MaterialID =" & DLookUp("[MaterialID]","[tbl_MaterialStock]","StockID =" & [FillerStockID]))
```